# Fluent Validation Handle Exception

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have some custom rules defined in an AbstractValidator class and I want that when there is an internal exception (e.g. NullReferenceException) in the rule definition, the validation process to return this in **Errors** collection. Now, when encounters an exception, the validation stops and that exception is thrown.

```
 RuleFor(order => order.Products).Must(products =>
{
    HashSet<string> domains = products
        .SelectMany(product => product.Stock.Domains)
        .Select(domain => domain.Name)
        .ToHashSet();

    return domains.Count >= distinctDomains;
}).When(order => order.Products.Count >= maxProductsCount)
```

E.g. When *Domains* property is null, an exception is thrown and the validation stops. I want the validation process to continue, and to append somehow what happened in **Errors** collection (from ValidationException).

Are there any options to obtain such a behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't had a chance to test this myself, but you should be able to catch the exception inside the Must validator and then set the Rule Message (using the current context) to the exception's error message (or whatever you want).  This allows you to not need to use the WithMessage method, but just set the message inside your logic.  This will trap the exception and allow processing to continue, but with the exception message as an error.

Something like:

```
RuleFor(order => order.Products).Must((order, products, context) =>
{
    try {
       HashSet<string> domains = products
          .SelectMany(product => product.Stock.Domains)
          .Select(domain => domain.Name)
          .ToHashSet();

       return domains.Count >= distinctDomains;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        context.Rule.MessageBuilder = c => ex.Message;
        return false;
    }
}).When(order => order.Products.Count >= maxProductsCount)
```